# Initialize service in controller constructor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, autofac

I would like to use autofac IoC to initialize my service that injected into MVC controller constructor. Assume service interface looks like this:

```
 public interface IService
{
    void SetValidationContainer(IReadOnlyDictionary<string, ModelStateEntry>  validations);
}
```

And controller ctor:

```
 public class HelloWorldController : Controller
{
    private readonly IService _service;
    public HelloWorldController(IService service)
    {
        _service = service;
        _service.SetValidationContainer(ModelState);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to move calling "SetValidationContainer(ModelState)" to DI config? And use something like this:

```
  container.Register<IService>
            .As<ServiceImplementaion>
            .AfterInjectedInto<Controller>
            .Call(service, controller => service.SetValidationContainer(controller.ModelState));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Autofac* provides 3 events.

- `OnActivating` : raised before a component is used
- `OnActivated` : raised once a component is fully constructed
- `OnRelease` : raised when a component is disposed

In your case, you could use the `OnActivated` to initialize your component.

```
builder.RegisterType<Service>()
       .As<IService>()
       .OnActivating(e => e.Instance.Initialize());
```

Have a look at *Autofac* [Lifetime Events](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/lifetime/events.html) documentation for more information